# PHP combine matching rows from associative arrays from sql and display results in html

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 results set

```
$result_a = @pg_query($rquery_a);
$result_b = @pg_query($rquery_b);
```

I have 2 arrays to host and display the data on an html page:

```
$datas_a = array();
$datas_b = array();
```

$datas_a gets this data:

```
$i=0;
while ($row = @pg_fetch_assoc($result_a)){
    $datas_a[$i] = array('s1' => $row['salle'],
                        'duree_occu' => $row['duree_resa']);
    $i++;
    }
```

and $datas_b gets this data:

```
$i=0;
while ($row = @pg_fetch_assoc($result_b)){
    $datas_b[$i] = array('s1' => $row['salle'],
                        'duree_cours' => $row['duree_cours']);
    $i++;
    }
```

From these 2 existing arrays with same number of rows and same keys, I would like 3 columns, 1 column is the same for both arrays ($datas_a and $datas_b), the second column is from $datas_a and the third column is from $datas_b

It currently looks like this for $datas_a

[$datas_a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z9E7.png)

It currently looks like this for $datas_b

[$datas_b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPJnl.png)

It should look like this

[merging columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkTRs.png)

**Now, I have used**

`$dataComb = array_merge($datas_a, $datas_b)`;

but it puts one array on top of the other while I would like to just add a column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$i=0;
foreach ($datas_a as $data) {
    $dataComb[$i]["s1"] = $data["s1"];
    $dataComb[$i]["duree_resa"] = $data["duree_resa"];
    $i++;
}

$i=0;
foreach ($datas_b as $data) {
    $dataComb[$i]["duree_cours"] = $data["duree_cours"];
    $i++;
}
```

Edit - 2021-08-20

Or for something more robust given it's a basic way I only know to do this

```
$datas_a = array(); // associative array
$datas_b = array();
$dataComb = []; // indexed array

$i=0;
while ($row = @pg_fetch_assoc($result_a)){
    $datas_a[$i] = array('s1' => $row['salle'],
                        'duree_resa' => $row['duree_resa']);
    $i++;
    }

$i=0;
while ($row = @pg_fetch_assoc($result_b)){
    $datas_b[$i] = array('s1' => $row['salle'],
                        'duree_cours' => $row['duree_cours']);
    $i++;
    }

$i=0;
if($a>=$b){
    foreach($datas_a as $dataa) {
        $dataTmp[$i][0] = $dataa["s1"];
        $dataTmp[$i][1] = $dataa["duree_resa"];
        foreach($datas_b as $datab) {
            if($dataa["s1"] == $datab["s1"] ){
                $dataTmp[$i][2] = $datab["duree_cours"];
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
elseif($a<$b){
        foreach($datas_b as $datab) {
            $dataTmp[$i][0] = $datab["s1"];
            $dataTmp[$i][1] = $datab["duree_resa"];
            foreach($datas_a as $dataa) {
                if($datab["s1"] == $dataa["s1"] ){
                    $dataTmp[$i][2] = $dataa["duree_cours"];
                }
            }
            $i++;
        }
}

$nb_lig = $a>=$b ? $a : $b;

for ($row=0; $row<=$nb_lig; $row++) {
    $dataComb[$row]["s1"] = $dataTmp[$row][0];
    $dataComb[$row]["duree_resa"] = $dataTmp[$row][1];
    $dataComb[$row]["duree_cours"] = $dataTmp[$row][2];
}
```

And there is $dataComb as an associative array that combines the data from previous arrays with matching records

```
foreach ($dataComb as $data){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$data["s1"].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$data["duree_resa"].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$data["duree_cours"].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```